# python web crawling in same class

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python and webcrawling.

Consider this web site : https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AWR?p=AWR

I want crawling Forward Dividend & Yield but it works strangly: it prints 'Ex-Dividend Date'

here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import requests
import yfinance as yf
import time
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



def web_content_div(web_content,class_path):
    web_content_div = web_content.find_all('div',{'class': class_path})
    try:
        spans = web_content_div[0].find_all('span')
        texts = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
    except IndexError:
        texts = []
    
    return texts

def real_time_price(stock_code):
    
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code + '?p=' + stock_code 
   
    try :
        r = requests.get(url)
        web_content = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
        texts = web_content_div(web_content, 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)')
        if texts != []:
            price, change = texts[0],texts[1]
        else:
            price , change = [] , []
    
    #############################################################it doesn't works#####################################################
        texts = web_content_div(web_content,'D(ib) W(1/2) Bxz(bb) Pstart(12px) Va(t) ie-7_D(i) ie-7_Pos(a) smartphone_D(b) smartphone_W(100%) smartphone_Pstart(0px) smartphone_BdB smartphone_Bdc($seperatorColor)')
        if texts != []:
            for count, div in enumerate(texts):
                if div == 'Forward Dividend & Yield':
                   dividend = texts[count + 1]
        else:
            dividend = []
    #############################################################it doesn't works#####################################################
        
        texts = web_content_div(web_content,'D(ib) W(1/2) Bxz(bb) Pstart(12px) Va(t) ie-7_D(i) ie-7_Pos(a) smartphone_D(b) smartphone_W(100%) smartphone_Pstart(0px) smartphone_BdB smartphone_Bdc($seperatorColor)')
        if texts != []:
            for count, EX in enumerate(texts):
                if EX == 'Ex-Dividend Date':
                    EXdate = texts[count + 1]
        else:
            EXdate = []


    
        texts = web_content_div(web_content,'D(ib) W(1/2) Bxz(bb) Pend(12px) Va(t) ie-7_D(i) smartphone_D(b) smartphone_W(100%) smartphone_Pend(0px) smartphone_BdY smartphone_Bdc($seperatorColor)')
        if texts != []:
            for count, vol in enumerate(texts):
                if vol == 'Volume':
                    volume = texts[count + 1]
        else:
            volume = []

   
        texts = web_content_div(web_content, 'D(ib) W(1/2) Bxz(bb) Pstart(12px) Va(t) ie-7_D(i) ie-7_Pos(a) smartphone_D(b) smartphone_W(100%) smartphone_Pstart(0px) smartphone_BdB smartphone_Bdc($seperatorColor)')
        if texts != []:
            for count, target in enumerate(texts):
                if target == '1y Target Est':
                    one_year_target = texts[count +1]

        else:
            one_year_target = []


    except ConnectionError:
        price, change,dividend, EXdate,volume,one_year_target = [],[],[],[],[],[]

    return price, change,dividend, EXdate,volume,one_year_target


stock=['awr','aapl']


while(True):
    info = []
    col = []
    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=13)
    time_stamp = time_stamp.strftime('%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S')
    for stock_code in stock:
        price, change,dividend, EXdate,volume,one_year_target = real_time_price(stock_code)
        info.append(price)
        info.extend([change])
        info.extend([dividend])
        info.extend([EXdate])
        info.extend([volume])
        info.extend([one_year_target])
        time.sleep(5)

    col = [time_stamp]
    col.extend(info)
    print(col)
```

and it print

```
'2021-41-03/14/21 19:41:16', '72.16', '+0.38 (+0.53%)', 'Ex-Dividend Date', 'Feb 12, 2021', '288,352', '77.00',
```

Comment: Did you expect it to print the "Forward Dividend & Yield" value where it currently prints `'Ex-Dividend Date'`?

Comment: exactly yes! that's what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because, for some reason, the Yahoo page doesn't put a `span` around the value you were looking to read.

For example, this is what I'm seeing for the result you linked:

```
<tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) " data-reactid="108">
  <td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)" data-reactid="109">
    <span data-reactid="110">Forward Dividend &amp; Yield</span>
  </td>
  <td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD-value" data-reactid="111">1.34 (1.86%)</td>
</tr>
```

So, instead of `spans = web_content_div[0].find_all('span')`, you'll want to match the appropriate `td`s themselves and get their text instead of the `span`s inside.

A quick test shows that just using this works for that field, but breaks some of the others:

```
spans = web_content_div[0].find_all('td')
```

So, it's clearly not the full solution, but shows that this is indeed the problem. You'll need to come up with a selection criterium that matches all the values you're interested in.

Also note that you repeatedly call `web_content_div`, where you could also just retrieve it once and reuse it.